# When do "choice_id" and "other_id" appear or not?

Tags: surveymonkey

I used to see "choice_id" in the answers.
 Here is one for "Other (please specify)" (numbers edited for privacy)

```
Question "id": "988.....",
"answers": [{"choice_id": "1039......."},
{"text": "I had this problem",
"other_id": "1039......"}]
```

Now I have a response without choice_id

```
{"id":"2420.....","answers":[{"text":"my text response here","other_id":"1712......"}]},
```

Why is choice_id missing? "is_answer_choice" is TRUE in the survey details:

```
{"id":"1712......","visible":true,"is_answer_choice":true,
"apply_all_rows":false,
"text":"Other (please specify)",
"position":0,"num_chars":50,
"error_text":"Please enter a comment.",
"num_lines":1},"choices":[...etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a question that is say a single choice with 3 choices and the option to allow open ended answers enabled then you have 3 choices and one other choice - which are modelled differently.

So if the user submits a response choosing a regular choice, the response body looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "answers": [
        {
            "choice_id": "313"
        }
    ]
}
```

But if the user selects an option to the "other" choice and put in an open ended response, the body looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "answers": [
        {
            "text": "My open ended response",
            "other_id": "314"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the survey details, you should also see something like this:

```
"answers": {
    "other": {
        "id": "110",
        "text": "Other (please specify)",
        ...
    },
    "choices": [
        {
            "visible": true,
            "text": "a",
            "position": 1,
            "id": "111"
        },
        {
            "visible": true,
            "text": "b",
            "position": 2,
            "id": "112"
        },
        {
            "visible": true,
            "text": "c",
            "position": 3,
            "id": "113"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which shows the other choice modelled differently than the answer choices. The `is_answer_choice` option in the `other` is actually just a display option. If the value is `false` then in the user interface it shows up as a comment box below the question, if it is `true` then it shows up in the list with the other choices.

Comment: Thank you Kandalaft, your example describes the second case I have above  Under what circumstances do I get the first case, with BOTH a choice_id AND an other_id?

Comment: Hmm I don't recall if there is a case where you would get both. There is a case where you other option has `apply_all_rows` for a matrix question, in which case there should be a `row_id` associated with which row the other choice was answered on.

Comment: Thanks Kandalaft, I'll privately email Surveymonkey API support with the surveyID showing the first case.

Comment: If it helps, the JSON for the first case is this: I think the difference is is_answer_choice is false, but I'll check with support:

    {"sorting":null,"family":"single_choice","subtype":"vertical","required":null,"answers":{"other":{"id":"103..","visible":true,"is_answer_choice":false,"apply_all_rows":false,"text":"If \"No\", what went wrong?","position":0,"num_chars":50,"error_text":"","num_lines":3},"choices":[{"visible":true,"text":"Yes","position":1,"id":"103..."},{"visible":true,"text":"No","position":2,"id":"103..."}]

--